# Cannot access file in Network Attached Storage (NAS) by using C++ access() function?

Tags: c++, networking, nas

I have an Isilon NAS in 10.20.30.11 for example, and I mounted it like following:

```
mount 10.20.30.11:/folder /content
```

I could use `ls` command to find the file in folder or `/content`. Its mod is 777.

```
bash-3.00# ls -l /content/a/b/1.txt

total 344131

rwxrwxrwx   1 1005     65533    140750 Feb 28 00:58 1.txt
```

But I cannot access it by access() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cerrno>

using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    int returnVal = 0;
    returnVal = access(argv[1], R_OK);
    cout << returnVal << endl;
    cout << errno << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It will return -1 and 2 as a result, which means 'No such file or directory'.

```
./a.out /content/a/b/1.txt

-1 

2

#define ENOENT   2 /* No such file or directory */
```

It is not a permission problem I think, because the mod is 777, and the result is 'No such file or directory'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Linux man pages.

> access() may not work correctly on NFS
>   file systems with UID mapping enabled,
>   because UID mapping is done on the
>   server and hidden from the client,
>   which checks permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it is found that it need to use following command to mount the Isilon storage.

> mount -o vers=2,proto=tcp
>   1.2.3.4:/remote /mnt

The version and protocol need specified.

Thanks!